# wordpress fullscreen responsive image map on homepage

Tags: wordpress, responsive-design, fullscreen, html, imagemap

For purposes of your visualization here is what I need;

**Within WordPress I need the homepage to be a fullscreen (or almost) "image map" of the united states that is responsive so that it re-sizes from phones to TV's**

I need this on the homepage and nothing else, no logins, widgets etc. just the image map(hot spots for each state).

It sounds really simple, I am hoping someone has come across a theme or mod that does this.

P.S. I have an image map already and can deal with the responsive part, but I don’t know how to use it in WordPress as a full page.

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a [custom page template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/#creating-custom-page-templates-for-global-use) (suppose template-home.php)and paste the code you have in that file. Then start making it dynamic by replacing static html with [wordpress functions](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference). You can make header-home.php and footer-home.php and use:

```
<?php get_header('home');

//rest of the stuff here

 get_footer('home');?>
```

in order to make it full screen use [this technique](https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/).